# Prometheus Query for 24 hour snapshots

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

is there a way to query prometheus and return 24hour snapshots of a metric over the course of a week?

Details about the metric:

- Name: foo
- Type: Gauge
- Value: 1

The metric is scraped every minute and the `value` will vary like so

[image]

I want to turn this into something that looks like

[image]

Which is taking a rollup of all the values within a 24hour period and creating a single sum'd value for each day.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible with [Prometheus subqueries](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/). For example, the following query should return per-day averages for the `metric`:

```
last_over_time(
  avg_over_time(metric[1d])[1d:1d]
)
```

Note that the returned results will be shifted 1 day forward because Prometheus performs calculations over lookbehind windows in square brackets. This can be fixed by adding `offset -1d` inside the query:

```
last_over_time(
  avg_over_time(metric[1d] offset -1d)[1d:1d]
)
```

Unfortunately the given query with negative offset doesn't work in Prometheus older than [v2.33.0](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/releases/tag/v2.33.0). But this query works perfectly in all the versions of [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/) - the Prometheus-like monitoring system I work on.

Comment: This is extremely close to what Im trying to do, the only thing that is unfavorable is that it shows every point that was reported rather than a sum of the whole day per se
**EDIT** the issue is in grafana not prometheus... thanks @valyala